# How to filter for rows across any columns for non zero

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I would like to filter my dataframe to obtain all rows that have no zero in any columns.

Here's my dataframe:

```
df1 = structure(list(item = c(NA, "polygon", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "polygon", 
"polygon", "0", NA, "polygon", "polygon"), identity = c("pol", 
"0", NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", "pol", "pol", "0", NA, "pol", "pol"
), unique = c("polx", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "polx", "0", 
"0", NA, "polx", "0"), detect = c("ox", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "ox", "0", NA, "ox", NA), structure = c("hex", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", NA, "hex", "hex", "0", NA, "hex", "hex"), key = c("IUGDG", 
"0", "0", "0", NA, "0", NA, "IUGDG", "IUGDG", "0", NA, "IUGDG", 
"IUGDG"), code = c("adg434kk", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0", NA, "adg434kk", 
"adg434kk", "0", NA, "adg434kk", "adg434kk")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

      item identity unique detect structure   key     code
1     <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
2  polygon        0      0      0         0     0        0
3     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0
4     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0
5     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0  <NA>     <NA>
6     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0
7     <NA>        0      0   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
8  polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
9  polygon      pol      0     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
10       0        0      0      0         0     0        0
11    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
12 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
13 polygon      pol      0   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
```

Expected output

```
      item identity unique detect structure   key     code
1     <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
8  polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
11    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
12 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
```

All the attempts I have tried below failed:

```
df1 %>%
  filter(!if_any(item:code, ~ .x == 0))

df1 %>%
  filter(if_any(item:code, ~ .x != 0))
```

Using anti_join provides the solution but is there a more direct way?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(if_any(item:code, ~ .x == 0))
anti_join(df1, df2)
```

Most of the solutions I found is changing 0 to NA but I want to find all rows with 0.
Can someone provides a solution using dplyr, that is with piping approach? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `if_all` with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(if_all(item:code, ~ !.x  %in% 0))
```

-output

```
  item identity unique detect structure   key     code
1    <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
2 polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
3    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
4 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
```

---

Or with `if_any` with `%in%`

```
df1 %>%
    filter(!if_any(item:code, ~ .x %in% 0))
 item identity unique detect structure   key     code
1    <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
2 polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
3    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
4 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
```

If we want to use `==` or `!=`, make sure that `NA` values are taken care of

```
df1 %>%
  filter(!if_any(item:code, ~ .x == 0 & !is.na(.x)))
 item identity unique detect structure   key     code
1    <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
2 polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk
3    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
4 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk
```

---

The difference is that `==` or `!=` returns `NA` when there is an `NA` whereas `%in%` returns `FALSE` for the `NA`.  When there is `NA` as return value, `filter` removes those rows.  If we create a column, it becomes more clear

```
> df1 %>%
       mutate(new = if_any(item:code, ~ .x != 0))
      item identity unique detect structure   key     code   new
1     <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
2  polygon        0      0      0         0     0        0  TRUE
3     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0    NA
4     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0    NA
5     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0  <NA>     <NA>    NA
6     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0    NA
7     <NA>        0      0   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>    NA
8  polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
9  polygon      pol      0     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
10       0        0      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
11    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>    NA
12 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
13 polygon      pol      0   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
```

whereas with `%in%`

```
> df1 %>% mutate(new = !if_any(item:code, ~ .x %in% 0))
      item identity unique detect structure   key     code   new
1     <NA>      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
2  polygon        0      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
3     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
4     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
5     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0  <NA>     <NA> FALSE
6     <NA>     <NA>      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
7     <NA>        0      0   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA> FALSE
8  polygon      pol   polx   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
9  polygon      pol      0     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk FALSE
10       0        0      0      0         0     0        0 FALSE
11    <NA>     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  TRUE
12 polygon      pol   polx     ox       hex IUGDG adg434kk  TRUE
13 polygon      pol      0   <NA>       hex IUGDG adg434kk FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This is super great answer. Btw, I'm still confused with when to have the `!` in `!if_any` or sometimes `~!.x` or `!is.na(.x)`. Can you pls kindly explain this?

Comment: @Catalyst `if_any` returns TRUE if any of the columns looped returns TRUE for a row,  whereas `if_all` returns TRUE only if all the columns in the loop returns TRUE.  If we understand this, it becomes easier.  In the first code, `if_all(item:code, ~ !.x  %in% 0)`, we loop over each of the columns item to code separately, and create a logical vector which returns TRUE if the value of the column is not a 0 (`!.x %in% 0`).  If these are TRUE for all the columns for a row, then only `if_all` returns TRUE i.e. none of the elements are 0.

Comment: @Catalyst  In addition, for `NA` elements, `x %in% 0` returns FALSE, thus the negate (`!`) returns TRUE.  Similarly, if you think in `if_any`, the `.x == 0 & !is.na(.x)` returns TRUE for a column (row) if the value is 0 and is not an NA.  Thus, for all other cases it will be FALSE.  When we use `if_any`, it is returning TRUE if there is any column that have 0 for a row.  Negating, returns the opposite i.e. row have only non zero.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It's clear to me now. :)